# How can I create a model in Powerdesigner which can generate create script for different database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, powerdesigner, physical-design

I just want to create the model once, and then use it in any kind of database, without the need to modify the model.

What I should do with the data type ? I found there is numeric and other kind of data types. What does that correspond to in mysql or access ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that any real variances or customizations between physical implementation of the model (like physical storage, which is decidedly non-portable syntax) will be lost.

What you should probably do in that case is either:

- Maintain a logical data model, then convert it to a physical data model at for the target platform.

or

- Maintain multiple parallel physical data models.

Answer (score 0):

PowerDesigner lets you create a conceptual data model that can be used as source for the creation of several physical data model, each one associated to a specific DBMS. Updates made to the conceptual data model, for example a new table, can then be automatically incorporated into the several physical data models previously created.

The data types used in the conceptual model will be mapped to a specific data type for the selected DBMS. You can control these mappings and can even create custom DBMS configurations. In PowerDesigner 12.5, see (Tools->Resources->DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any user-defined data types (for which Sybase of course cannot provide predefined mapping rules), you can create a mapping procedure yourself using the metamodel editor or -if you need to remap only specific columns inside the generated model- in the mapping editor.